# How to specify numrows in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

How to do specify the numrows var in app script ? I tried using this one

var startRow = 11;

var numRows = lastRow - startRow + 1;

The thing is that i want to read values on the first 9th columns , because in the 10th column i have some values that i want to be fix in this sheet. i want them to be ignored and to read onlu the other values

Thanks in advance and sr for my english

The thing is that i want to read values on the first 9th columns , because in the 10th column i have some values that i want to be fix in this sheet. i want them to be ignored and to read onlu the other values

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/ help?

Answer (score 0):

numrows = sheet.getLastRow() - startrow + 1

numcols = sheet.getLastColumn() - startcol + 1

Answer (score 0):

ok i understand this , i have this in my script does it work the same ?

// Calculate the last row and last column of the source sheet

var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();

var lastColumn = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();